# Equivalent of R geosphere::distGeo in Python

Tags: python, r, spatial, geopy, geosphere

I am translating R code to Python. I can't find a function to match the output of R function `geosphere::distGeo` in Python.
I have looked at a lot of answers here and it seems the Python equivalent is `geopy.distance.geodesic`, but the results don't match. R code gives 440km and Python code give 392km.

I am looking for a Python function (or maybe just parameters the good parameters ?) to match the 440km given by R.

I have tried this :

R code

```
lyon = c(45.7597, 4.8422) # (latitude, longitude)
paris = c(48.8567, 2.3508)
geosphere::distGeo(lyon, paris) / 1000 # default is WGS84 and meters
# 440.7626 km
```

Python code

```
from geopy.distance import geodesic
lyon = (45.7597, 4.8422) # (latitude, longitude)
paris = (48.8567, 2.3508)
geodesic(lyon, paris, ellipsoid="WGS-84").km
# 392.4315 km
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R [`geosphere::distGeo()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/geosphere/versions/1.5-18/topics/distGeo) expects  `c(lon, lat)` and [`geopy.distance.geodesic()`](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html?highlight=geodesic#geopy.distance.geodesic) expects `(lat, lon)`.

Strangely this is not made explicit in the docs but you can see it in the [source](https://github.com/ulope/geopy/blob/605d0d84137a93949ad03820fa31dc2dab77f089/geopy/distance.py#L132).

In any case just switch the order:

```py
from geopy.distance import geodesic
lyon = (4.8422, 45.7597)
paris = (2.3508, 48.8567)
geodesic(lyon, paris, ellipsoid="WGS-84").km
# 440.76257985857796
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I copy pasted without thinking it could be other way  in Python ...